# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if 1:
T1=300
P1=1
h1=462
s1=4.42
hf=29
sf=0.42
print("The inlet conditions to compressor are 1atm pressure & 300K")
Wi=(T1*(s1-sf))-(h1-hf)
P2= input("What is the final compression pressure? ")
T2= input("What is the final compression temperature? ")
h2= float(input("From graph, enthalpy at point 2 is "))
s2= float(input("From graph, entropy at point 2 is "))
y= float((h1-h2)/(h1-hf))
W= float((T1*(s1-s2))-(h1-h2))
Wf= float(W/y)
FOM= float(Wi/Wf)
print("")
print("Yield= %f") %(y)
print("Work reqd per unit mass of gas compressed= %f KJ/kg") %(W)
print("Work reqd per unit mass of gas liquified= %f KJ/kg") %(Wf)
print("Figure of Merit= %f") %(FOM)
```

The inlet conditions to compressor are 1atm pressure & 300K
What is the final compression pressure? 20
What is the final compression temperature? 300
From graph, enthalpy at point 2 is 432
From graph, entropy at point 2 is 2.74

Yield= %f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 19, in 
    print("Yield= %f") %(y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Comment: The `print` function returns `None` and then you apply the `%` operator to it with the value of `y`, which is a `float`, so you get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'float'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the last 4 lines of your code. You need parenthesis `()` around each expression in those statements. You can't apply `%` on `print` function because it returns `None`

Your last 4 lines of code should look like

```
print(("Yield= %f") % (y))
print(("Work reqd per unit mass of gas compressed= %f KJ/kg") %(W))
print(("Work reqd per unit mass of gas liquified= %f KJ/kg") %(Wf))
print(("Figure of Merit= %f") %(FOM))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be applying `%` formatting on the string but currently you are applying it on `None` (value returned by `print` function). In order to make your code work, you should be doing:

```
print("Yield= %f" % (y)) 
#                 ^ moved inside `(...)` of print
```

instead of:

```
print("Yield= %f") %(y)
```